# What is the big deal with BUILDING 64-bit versions of binaries?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, vista64

There are a ton of drivers & famous applications that are not available in 64-bit. Adobe for instance does not provider a 64-bit Flash player plugin for Internet Explorer. And because of that, even though I am running 64-bit Vista, I have to run 32-bit IE. Microsoft Office, Visual Studio also don't ship in 64-bit AFAIK.

Now personally, I haven't had much problems building my applications in 64-bit. I just have to remember a few rules of thumb, e.g. always use SIZE_T instead of UINT32 for string lengths etc.

So my question is, what is preventing people from building for 64-bit?

Answer (score 16):

If you are starting from scratch, 64-bit programming is not that hard.  However, all the programs you mention are not new.

It's a whole lot easier to build a 64-bit application from scratch, rather than port it from an existing code base.  There are many gotchas when porting, especially when you get into applications where some level of optimization has been done.  Programmers use lots of little assumptions to gain speed, and these are not always easy to quickly port to 64-bit.  A few examples I've had to deal with:

- Proper alignment of elements within a struct.  As data sizes change, assumptions that certain fields in a struct will be aligned on an optimal memory boundary may fail
- Length of `long` integers change, so if you pass values over a socket to another program that may not be 64-bit, you need to refactor your code
- Pointer lengths change, as so hard to decipher code written be a guru that has left the company become a little trickier to debug
- Underlying libraries will also need to have 64-bit support to properly link.  This is a large part of the problem of porting code if you rely on any libraries that are not open source

Comment: Platforms that use an LLP64 programming model (such as Microsoft Windows on x64) do not have 64-bit long integers.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the things in [@jvasak's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160082/what-is-the-big-deal-with-building-64-bit-versions-of-binaries#160139), the major thing that can causes bugs:

- pointers are larger than ints - a huge amount of code makes the assumption that the sizes are the same.

Remember that Windows will not even allow an application (whether 32-bit or 64-bit) to handle pointers that have an address above 0x7FFFFFFF (2GB or above) unless they have been specially marked as `"LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE"` because so many applications will treat the pointer as a negative value at some point and fall over.

Answer (score 5):

The biggest issues that I've run into porting our C/C++ code to 64 bit is support from 3rd party libraries. E.g. there is currently only 32 bit versions of the Lotus Notes API and also MAPI so you can't even link against them.

Also since you can't load a 32 bit DLL into your 64 bit process you get burnt again trying to load things dynamically. We ran into this problem again trying to support Microsoft Access under 64 bit. From wikipedia:

> The Jet Database Engine will remain
>   32-bit for the foreseeable future.
>   Microsoft has no plans to natively
>   support Jet under 64-bit versions of
>   Windows

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, but I would think a large part of it would be support - If Adobe compiles the 64 bit version, they have to support it.  Even though it may be a simple compile switch, they'd still have to run through a lot of testing, etc, followed by training their support staff to respond correctly, when they do run into issues fixing them either results in a new version of the 32 bit binary or a branch in the code, etc.  So while it seems simple, for a large application it can still end up costing a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Another reason that a lot of companies have not gone through the effort of creating 64 bit versions is simply they don't need to.

Windows has WoW64 (Windows on Windows 64 bit) and Linux can have the 32 bit libraries available alongside the 64 bit.  Both of these allow us to run 32 bit applications in 64 bit environments.

As long as the software is able to run in this way, there is not a major incentive to convert to 64 bit.

Exceptions to this are things such as device drivers as they are tied in deeper with the operating systems and cannot run in the 32 bit layer that the x86-64/AMD64 based 64-bit operating systems offer (IA64 is unable to do this from what I understand).

I agree with you on flash player though, I am very disappointed in Adobe that they have not updated this product.  As you have pointed out, it does not work properly in 64 bit requiring you to run the 32 bit version of Internet Explorer.

I think it is a strategic mistake on Adobe's part.  Having to run the 32 bit browser for flash player is an inconvenience for users, and many will not understand this solution.  This could lead to developers being apprehensive about using flash.  The most important thing for a web site is to make sure everyone can view it, solutions that alienate users are typically not popular ones.  Flash's popularity was fed by its own popularity, the more sites that used it, the more users had it on their systems, the more users that had it on their systems, the more sites were willing to use it.

The retail market pushes these things forward, when a general consumer goes to buy a new computer, they aren't going to know they don't need a 64 bit OS they are going to get it either because they hear it is the latest and greatest thing, the future of computing, or just because they don't know the difference.

Vista has been out for about 2 years now, and Windows XP 64-bit was out before that.  In my mind that is too long for a major technology such as Flash to not be upgraded if they want to hold on to their market.  It may have to do with Adobe taking over Macromedia and this is a sign that Adobe does not feel Flash is part of their future, I find it hard to believe as I think Flash and Dreamweaver were the top parts of what they got out of Macromedia, but then why have they not updated it yet?

Answer (score 2):

It is not as simple as just flipping a switch on your compiler.  At least, not if you want to do it right.  The most obvious example is that you need to declare all your pointers using 64-bit datatypes.  If you have any code which makes assumptions about the size of these pointers (e.g. a datatype which allocates 4 bytes of memory per pointer), you'll need to change it.  All this needs to have been done in any libraries you use, too.  Further, if you miss just a few then you'll end up with pointers being down-casted and at the wrong location.  Pointers are not the only sticky point but are certainly the most obvious.

Comment: Well, sometimes I really feel lucky that I decided to (ab)use Java... *scnr ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Primarily a support and QA issue. The engineering work to build for 64-bit is fairly trivial for most code, but the testing effort, and the support cost, don't scale down the same way.

On the testing side, you'll still have to run all the same tests, even though you "know" they should pass.

For a lot of applications, converting to a 64-bit memory model doesn't actually give any benefit (since they never need more than a few GB of RAM), and can actually make things slower, due to the larger pointer size (makes every object field twice as large).

Add to that the lack of demand (due to the chicken/egg problem), and you can see why it wouldn't be worth it for most developers.

Answer (score 0):

Their [Linux/Flash blog](http://blogs.adobe.com/penguin.swf/2006/10/whats_so_difficult_64bit_editi.html) goes some way to explain why there isn't a 64bit Flash Player as yet. Some is Linux-specific, some is not.

Comment: The ActionScript JIT engine and garbage collection, to summarize.

Comment: That was two years ago, I don't buy that it is THAT hard.

Comment: They're about to release it, if you ask me. I'd put money on it coming out around the same time as CS4. CS5 at the latest.